# layout not work in android when using 'TextInputLayout'

Tags: android

[image]

hi, i am new for android,i use TextInputLayout for all EditText, but why it look like this (show in aimage) button is not set, when error massage is set than button come to down how it possible. 
code is :

```
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/windowBackground">
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:background="@color/windowBackground">

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_qty"
            android:layout_width="145dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_part"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="140dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/qty"
                android:numeric="decimal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:hint="Item Quantity"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:singleLine="true"/>
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_rate"
            android:layout_width="145dip"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/list_view_part"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/count"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/count">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="100dip"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/rate"
                android:numeric="decimal"
                android:inputType="numberDecimal"
                android:hint="Item Rate"
                android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background"
                android:singleLine="true" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="40dip"
            android:layout_height="40dip"
            android:text="@string/icon_add"
            android:id="@+id/add"
            android:layout_above="@+id/input_layout_price"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/input_layout_price"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/input_layout_price"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/input_layout_rate" />
    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I think that the red error text resets the height of the TextInputLayout elements. 
Did you try to set the layoutgravity (alignment) of the button to "top" so that changing the height does not effect?